# How to update in order and query the updated fields when updating in SQL in a single statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to calculate Dividend Factors in the DB and the basic calculation needed in a general way is `row2 field2 = (row2's field1) * (row1's field2)` where the `field2` is the value I need to both update and query at the same time i.e. when I calculate it for one row, I need the calculated value of the previous row for this row.

Now I have a temp table with has all the values and now I need to calculate the final values, but when I tried this:

```
    UPDATE
        #temp
    SET
        field2 = IsNull(
            (SELECT d2.field2 * d.field1 FROM #temp AS d2 WHERE d2.rowNr = d.rowNr - 1)
            ,d.field1
        )
    FROM
        #temp as d  
    ;
```

It always saw that the `field2` was always NULL and went with the default action, with it should do only for the first row.

Now currently there are only two methods I know for doing this:

1. Loop through the #temp with a cursor
2. Use a while statement and loop through the table that way (I opted for this one, because I thought there is no point in using a cursor for a small table of 10-20 rows max)

But I still would like to get this into a single statement, but I have no idea how to do this. I am using MS SQL 2008 R2.

**EDIT:**

This is the actual data I am working with: (Note, that all field2 values are NULL prior to the calculation and the data type is *money*)

```
field1      field2(expected values)
------      ----------------------
1,033       1,033
1,0363      1,0705
1,0558      1,1302
1,0157      1,1479
1,0188      1,1695
1,026       1,1999
1,0286      1,2342
1,0323      1,2741
1,0319      1,3147
```

Comment: Can you include sample data and expected output?

Comment: @TabAlleman Added sample data

Comment: How are you getting the RowNr field?   also if all Field2 values are NULL at the start, then why would you expect SomeValue * NULL to ever be anything other than NULL?

Comment: @TabAlleman The rowNr is actually defined as  `rowNr int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL` in the temporary table, so I do not need to worry about it, and the very first row's `field2` is `field1` unchanged, sorry I expected my example code to explain this part (this is why I am using `IsNull()` there), my bad, should have mentioned this as well.

Comment: I'm talking about this sentence in your edit:   "all field2 values are NULL prior to the calculation"    What does that mean?   That when you create #temp, and before the update, field2 is NULL in every row?

Comment: @TabAlleman yes, exactly

Comment: Really the accepted answer was better than my 5 line solution.

Comment: @Blam yes, because your magic did not work... sorry, I tried it out when you showed it and I also ruled it out because of it. I actually had tired it prior to asking in SO, it does something a bit different, I do apologize, I actually had a lot of work to do and I though I was bothering you as is, so neglected to reply to your edit, but thank you so much for your time. If you can get it to work like that, I would prefer it like that, but if it does not work it does not work.

Comment: Then you need to get your server checked cause it works just fine for me with your test data

Comment: If you had tied it prior to posting on SO then why did you comment "refactoring to d2.field1 holds no point"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay if I'm understanding this, you want to find field2 which is based on previous rows of field2 that were just calculated so you need either some form of loop or recursion. Try this recursive solution out:

### Setting Up Tables

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp;

DECLARE @yourTable TABLE (ID INT,field1 INT, field2 INT);
INSERT INTO @yourTable(ID,field1,field2)
VALUES  (1111,11,11),(2222,22,22),(3333,33,33);


SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) rowNr,
        ID,
        field1,
        field2 INTO #temp
FROM @yourTable;
```

### Calculating values

```
WITH cte_recursion
AS
(
    SELECT  TOP 1
            rowNR,
            ID,
            field1,
            field2,
            field1 AS dividend_factor
    FROM #temp A
    ORDER BY rowNr

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  B.rowNr,
            B.ID,
            B.field1,
            B.field2,
            B.field1 * A.dividend_factor
    FROM cte_recursion A
    INNER JOIN #temp B
    ON A.rowNr = B.rowNr - 1
)
```

### Actual Update

```
UPDATE @yourTable
SET field2 = B.dividend_factor
FROM @yourTable A
INNER JOIN cte_recursion B
    ON A.ID = B.ID
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

SELECT *
FROM @yourTable
```

Results:

```
ID          field1      field2
----------- ----------- -----------
1111        11          11
2222        22          242
3333        33          7986
```

Personally I wouldn't use the update because you have to constantly make sure the data is update to date. I'd much rather use the CTE I used to calculate the values and put it in  a view so that you know the values are ALWAYS up to date and you don't have to worry about running it. Either that or having a dividend_factor column in your actual table that will be NULL unless the value is updated. Just my two cents

Comment: I gotcha. I edited it. And just so you know what you call "WITH" is actually called a CTE, which stands for Common Table Expression.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE d1
   SET d1.field2 = IsNull(d2.field2 * d1.field1, d1.field1) 
  FROM #temp AS d1 
  left outer join #temp AS d2  
    on d2.rowNr = d1.rowNr - 1
```

magic

```
select d1.field1, EXP(SUM(LOG(d2.field1))) 
  from #temp AS d1 
  join #temp AS d2 
    on d2.rowNr <= d1.rowNr 
 group by d1.field1
```

op claims wrong answer
test for youself

```
drop table #temp; 
create table #temp (ID int, val money);
insert into #temp (ID, val) values 
  (1, 1.033)
, (2, 1.0363)     
, (3, 1.0558)      
, (4, 1.0157)     
, (5, 1.0188)     
, (6, 1.026)      
, (7, 1.0286)    
, (8, 1.0323)    
, (9, 1.0319);    
SELECT TOP 10  [t1].[ID], EXP(SUM(LOG([t2].[val]))) 
  from #temp AS t1 
  join #temp AS t2 
    on t2.[ID] <= t1.[ID] 
 group by t1.[ID] 
 order by t1.[ID]
```

Comment: Just tried it, it has the same basic problem, the `field2` is always NULL and goes into the default behavior and the very first row is completely ignored, because that does not fill the `JOIN` conditions

Comment: then use an outer join

Comment: well the first row is a minor concern, the main issue is with the fact that when it updates the `field2` the previous row's `field2` is always NULL no matter when it is updated

Comment: Try and refactor using d2.field1 in the set

Comment: Sorry, maybe I am missing what you want me to do, but refactoring to `d2.field1` holds no point, the basic problem is still with the fact, that when the update does the JOIN the initial table it uses has no values in `field2` and that where the NULL comes from, I tried to avoid this by using an inline query in the SET, but same problem, in essence this is simply a better version of the same code I made, but with the same core problem.

Comment: OK you have a problem.  If you can't refactor to d2.field1 you can't.  The point is  d2.field1 has a value.

Comment: yeah, I misunderstood how this works earlier... did the same mistake as well when I found the same solution in google. Thank you for the update, I finally got it working thanks to your edit and for my own solution I actually do prefer this, but I am still retaining the original answer as the correct one, because it is more universal, this only works when you need to multiply fields, but the other one can be used in different situations as well. Thank you for your strong magic, my SQL magic still has ways to go and you did help me out of a bind.

Comment: So it is better answer to the question as stated but it is still not the correct solution because it might not apply to another question.  You do know SO is for specific questions?

Comment: Stephan's answer is better to "this" question. The question is "How to update in order and query the updated fields when updating in SQL in a single statement" note the distinct lack of the "multiply fields from previous row" that simply my specific problem, but I tried to query the previous field in order to multiply with it. Get off your high horse and accept that Stephan gave a better answer that actually allows me to do this. And yes I do, but I also know that SO questions need to be useful to future readers as well, and that answer in MS SQL 2008 R2 is better for more users!

Comment: High horse? It produces the right answer to the specific question as stated and the test data (in 5 lines).   You stated you prefer this for the solution to your specific problem.   I am not the one on the high horse.